# Batch: Reading values from .properties file that contain special characters

Tags: batch-file, properties, delayedvariableexpansion

I have two files.

**values.properties**

```
user=username
password=Password1234!
```

**mybatch.bat**

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A IN (path/values.properties) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="user" set user=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="password" set password=%%B
    )
```

In the batch file, password's value is:

```
Password1234
```

So basically, the "!" disappear. I want to make "password" store any value, no matter what special characters will contain. How can I do this? I tried to escape the "!" be adding "password=^^%%B". Did not work.

Thank you.

Comment: Disable delayed expansion and you'll see it works; the problem is that `%%A` is expanded before delayed expansion occurs, which consumes the `!`...

Comment: I can't believe it! It worked. I still don't know why I've added the "EnableDelayedExpansion". I am working for some time to this script and it was needed somewhere. Thank you very much. Can you add your comment as an answer so I can approve it? You rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are expandion a `for` variable reference `%%A` while having [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled, which consumes the exclamation mark.

Therefore simply disable delayed expansion and your code works.

Let me recommend to use the quoted `set` syntax `set "user=%%B"` in order to avoid trouble with special characters.

Answer (score 3):

Excuse me. I can't resist the temptation to post this answer...

Supose you have a numeric variable, that may have the values 10, 25 and 50, and you want to add it to a total variable. You may do it this way:

```
if %num% equ 10 set /A total+=10
if %num% equ 25 set /A total+=25
if %num% equ 50 set /A total+=50
```

... or you may do it this way:

```
set /A total+=num
```

Which one would you prefer?

---

The problem with your code is that you Enable Delayed Expansion *at the moment* the assignment is done. Just remove it and, if you need it, just enable it later:

```
SETLOCAL
For /F "delims=" %%A IN (path/values.properties) DO set "%%A"

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Password=!password!
```

The other changes in the code are explained in the first part of this answer. The quotes around `%%A` are used to protect other special characters, like `&` or `>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information! As you probably found out, I just started to learn how to use batch files. I was trying to add comments in the .property file so that's why I wanted to get rid of all the special characters(I removed the comments anyway). I couldn't find a better way to assign the values from my property file.